# in a website, setting one cookie is better than setting many single cookies?

Tags: cookies, web

Suppose that you have to set 12 cookies, would it be better to store all of their values in a single "big" cookie or store each value on its own cookie?
I want to know if that improves website speed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the maximium size of a cookie is about 4k. If you need to store more data than that, then you're better off using several cookies.

i don't think there will be a big performance issue using multiple cookies. in my opinion, it may be more efficient to store each piece of data in its own cookie rather than parsing through a bogger cookie for each "crum" of data each time you need it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The number of cookies is hardly going to affect speed in any meaningful way since either they'll all be sent through the request separated by `Cookie:` headers, or you'll have one `Cookie:` header with data concatenated in your own way. Technically, the "faster" way would be to use one cookie.

In reality, this is a micro-optimization and you shouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

If there is any doubt the best thing to do is try it both ways and use a free utility like tcptrace to show you how much bandwidth each method consumes.  That should definitively give you your answer, because if there is a difference in performance between the two methods you've proposed, it is probably due to bandwidth consumption.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use sessions, which store the session ID in a cookie and store everything else in your database/filesystem referenced against that session ID. That way, the data is not sent on every request, only the session ID is.